# QT sqlite how to know when there are no more results?

Tags: qt, sqlite

I want to know when I got the last result returned for my query.

My current code:

```
if (db.isOpen()) {

    QSqlQuery query(db);

    ret = query.exec(QString("select * from history WHERE cID = '%1' order by date(time) ASC;").arg(channel));

    if (ret) {
        while (query.next()) {

            // How can i know that there are no more results to loop through here?
            addMessage(query.value(1).toString(), query.value(2).toString(), timeStr, "NO"); 
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why can't you use the return value of `next()`?

Comment: Why do you need the number of records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QSqlQuery::last () retrieves the last record in the result, if available, and positions the query on the retrieved record. After calling last() you can retrieve index of the last record and position the query before the first record using first() and previous() :

```
int lastRecordIndex = 0;
if(query.last())
{
    lastRecordIndex =  query.at();
    query.first();
    query.previous(); 
}

while (query.next()) {

    if(query.at()==lastRecordIndex)
    {
        //This is the last record
    }
    addMessage(query.value(1).toString(), query.value(2).toString(), timeStr, "NO"); 
}
```

Comment: Tried to do a qDebug() inside that if but cant get it to fire

Comment: `query.size()` is not supported with SQLite.

Comment: Yes query.size() is not supported by SQLite. I updated the answer.